# Is the purpose of setting the version number of a file using chattr similar to optomistic locking in a database?

Tags: xattr

For instance if you record the version number before editing the file, and check it again before saving the file, you can be assured that nobody else wrote to the file while you were editing it.  (although to be honest I don't see it changing the version number automatically when changing a file).

Comment: That's one use among many. I don't know why ext2 acquired the version number feature but I doubt that this was the main reason.